# Multiple URLs serving the same static page in Tomcat and Jersey?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I am using backbone.js for to do client side routing on my web application.

In order for this client side routing to work, I need all URLs return the same html page, and the routing will then be done on that page in JavaScript.

I am using Jersey + Tomcat for my static pages and servlets. How do I have all URLs serve up the same page? (i.e all URLs matching MyWebbApp/App/** to serve up my index.html page).

Thanks in advance!

edit:

What regex would I use?
I would like
MyWebApp/App
MyWebApp/App/
MyWebApp/App/other
MyWebApp/App/other/other...

all to be included. I tried to do it but I could not get 1 regex to cover all those cases for some reason. The closest I got was:

@Path("MyWebApp/App/{some_var_name_i_never_use: .*}")

but this did not cover the MyWebApp/App or MyWebApp/App/ case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jersey's filter for static content. Here's a [blog post](http://www.flamingpenguin.co.uk/blog/2010/09/02/serving-static-content-and-jersey/) about it. You'd just need to define another filter to handle mapping everything to your index.html page. Note that in Jersey 2.0 the parameter name was changed to `jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a servlet and redirect all the pages to a particular page

You could have a regex to get all the pages that need to be redirected

```
response.sendRedirect("page");
```

Comment: What regex would I use?
I would like
MyWebApp/App
MyWebApp/App/
MyWebApp/App/other
MyWebApp/App/other/other...

all to be included. I tried to do it but I could not get 1 regex to cover all those cases for some reason. The closest I got was:

@Path("MyWebApp/App/{some_var_name_i_never_use: .*}")

Comment: what about url.startsWith("MyWebApp/App/");

Comment: Doesn't that just return a boolean? Jersey takes in a @Path() annotation with the regex inside.